# jquery not working in PyQt

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, pyqt, qwebview

I am writing a small desktop app in PYQT python which has a QWeb View browser. I am adding a functionality to this browser that when user select any text using mouse and right click and press show xpath a javascript is executed to find the xpath.
Here is my code :

```
@pyqtSlot()
def slotshowxpath(self):

text = self.selectedText()
if not text:
    QMessageBox.information(self,"information","No Text Selected")
else:
    frame = self.page().mainFrame().documentElement()
    #print frame.toHtml()
    #abc = frame.document()
    #abc.evaluateJavaScript("alert('"+self.page().selectedHtml()+"');")
    frame.evaluateJavaScript("""var data = window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode; getXPath(data);

    function getXPath( element ){
    alert(element);
    var xpath = '';
    for ( ; (element && element.nodeType) == 1; element = element.parentNode )
    {
    var id = $(element.parentNode).children(element.tagName).index(element) + 1;
    id > 1 ? (id = '[' + id + ']') : (id = '');
    xpath = '/' + element.tagName.toLowerCase() + id + xpath;   
    }   
    alert(xpath);   
    return xpath;       
    }"""
        )
```

this query is working good till `$(element.parentNode).children` but not working for `$(element.parentNode).children(element.tagName).index(element) + 1`, can anybody help me in fixing this issue?

Comment: jquery is a third-party javascript library, so that won't work without downloading and running it as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually the problem was with the alert statement inside the query.its not getting executed inside but when i tried it outside the javascript after returning the value, it start working